# How to tell in jQuery if an element's background is transparent?

Tags: jquery

If 'element' has a transparent background

```
$('element').css('background-color')
```

returns 'transparent' in some browsers and 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)' in others.

I would have expected jQuery to have  cross-browser way of telling us if an element has a transparent background.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Try with `if ($('element').css('background-color') === 'transparent'){}`.

Comment: @Vucko that won't work in chrome

Comment: Why not both? `if ($('element').css('background-color') === 'transparent' || $('element').css('background-color') === 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'){}`

Comment: I'm looking for both now.  But I check this a lot of places and I just thought that jQuery might have a cleaner solution for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rgba(0,0,0,0) is the same as transparent. The last digit is how filled the color should be, 0 = transparent.

```
function background_color(element) {
    if (element.css('background-color') === 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'){
        return 'transparent';
    }
    return element.css('background-color');
}

background_color($('element')) // will do the trick
```

Comment: One thing to keep in mind: a value like `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)` will also be completely transparent. It doesn't matter what the first 3 values are as long as the last one is 0 so there's some small potential for false positives here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is too useful for you but you can add a [custom cssHook](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/) and do the processing in there. You can also probably define it so you can modify the return of `.css(background-color)` but I don't have enough experience with `cssHooks` to know how to not cause it to infinitely recurse :/

```
$.cssHooks["nBackgroundColor"] = {//proxy to .css("background-color") called with .css("n-background-color")
    get: function(elem) {
        var back = $(elem).css("background-color");
        return back === "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)" ? "transparent" : back;
    }, 
    set: function(elem, val){ return $(elem).css('background-color', val); }
};

$($("div")[10]).css('n-background-color');//=> transparent
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I don't think I'll use it here, but it's good to know about!